# debugging problem in xcode

Tags: iphone, debugging, simulator

I'm having a problem similar to [this question][1]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449072/debugging-problem-in-x-code-iphone-development

I have created an application, but when  i try to debug it, the breakpoints are created i yellow.The only difference from the above link is that, a message is shown in xcode status bar that GDB:Warning No location found for MapViewController.m 18. MapViewController is ma viewController class.
I don't know what is the problem with it. The funny thing is that the application is working without any problem. But still i need to debug it. pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode's prefs, go to the debugging section and uncheck "load symbols lazily".